# Angular 5: run function in template on observable results in several calls to function

Tags: angular

## Template (html)

```
<div *ngFor="let item of toArray(observerable_val)">
    {{item.name}}
</div>
```

## Component

```
toArray(obj_obj) {
    const arr_obj = Object.values(obj_obj);
    return arr_obj;
}
```

## Question

Since ngFor does not iterate over objects I made this function to convert my `obj of obj` to `arr of obj`... This looks like it works fine but when i `console.log` in `toArray()` I notice that it keeps printing stuff indefinitely. Is that bad? if so What is another way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `async` pipe? Add `async` pipe in ngFor and you don't need to have any convert function. 
`<div *ngFor="let item of observerable_val | async">
    {{item.name}}
</div>`

Comment: I get this error when trying `InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`

Comment: The result you received is not observable.

Comment: when you you async pipe, you don't need to subcribed in the component. ex:  in your component: `observerable_val = yourservice.getObservable()`

Comment: Or if you want to use subcribe function, you should convert the response immediately. ``getObjects() {
  this.yourService.getObjects().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.objects= [];
      for(let key in data){
          this.objects.push(data[key]);
       }
    });
}``

Answer (score 0):

IF you are truly getting an observable array of objects then define something like `values: Observable<any[]>;` , set `this.values = 'observable array objects '` (ngOnInit maybe) and `<div *ngFor="let item of values | async">`